# Magento2.4: Is it Okay to upgrade magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I want to upgrade Magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 and also want to upgrade ubuntu from 20 to 22.04, should I update or not, people are getting some issues on upgrade, is there any idea how to solve those basic issues which occur in the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are good at fixing bugs and resolving issues during upgrades, you should update and also have a backup of your projects in case they cause any issues.
So far I only encounter a **rtrim()** error which was due to a missing PHP library,
other than that no issues
There are no bugs that can't be fixed and no issues which can't be resolved.

> sudo php bin/magento php7.4-mcrypt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update both easily.
For magento , there are no major issue after 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, and no need to **rtrim()** error for php , you can easily add library from php official site.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=MAGNETO+2.4.4&type=issues
For storage increase memory_limit in php and give space for magento in storage.